Geometry Node: how to offset vertex position in world space

I want to offset vertex position of multiple objects in one direction only, regardless of their own rotations. This is very simple in Unity or Unreal Engine (for example: using a noise texture to replicate a wind effect), somehow I can not figure how to do this using geometry node in Blender. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Just for clarification: is it necessary that those objects all have their own Geometry Nodes modifier like in your example? Why not use a single GN object to control them all? (Yeah I know this sounds a bit LOTR)

@GordonBrinkmann Yes it is necessary that those objects all have their own Geometry Nodes, since I need to control each object separately outside of GN.

This is not very clear and might be helpful information in your question or otherwise people might come up with solutions that do not respect that...

Does this answer your question? How do you invert a transformation in geometry nodes? I closed as duplicate of it, because all you need is to reverse the transformation, offset, and reapply the transformation. If that's not clear, please [Edit] your question and show where you have trouble and someone will reopen. Cheers! [Apparently I didn't close it just flagged it, because it's missing Geometry-Nodes tag :D]

you can try this node setup (if you are using the newest alpha 4.3):

by changing the combine xyz node, you can move your vertices in world space.

Additionally: in 4.2 you can plug the Rotation output of the Object Info node into the Transform Point node, works the the same - unless you need to compensate for a changed scale, then you can use a Vector Math node to divide the vector by the Object Info > Scale before plugging it into the Set Position node.

We should have this from the start :) You could also copy-paste this answer to the linked duplicate.
